# File copying slows down when copying multiple files at once

Tags: ssd

When transferring large files I get an avg transfer with a pretty good rate of around 50MB/s. Then I tried to transfer a folder that contained around 80K small files (around 1-100KB each) and I'm now getting transfer rates around 200KB/s. Does anyone have any info about why there is such a dramatic loss of write speed?

As you can see in this picture, when it goes fast it is copying a single large file, but when it slows down it copies multiple small files; 300 files 1kb each in 20 secs, should be more like less then 1 second for 300kb. This is only when copying a lot of small files not a lot of large files.

[image]

Comment: what are you writing to and what OS? I presume it is Windows 8 writing to a USB flash drive, but is it USB2 or USB3 (or USB1!) port and what is the exact make/model of the flash drive? Different ports and different drives have different speed capabilities (even though they may be described as 'USB2' or 'USB3' they are not all equal). But speed of 200K/s writing to a flash drive seems very slow indeed.

Comment: @fixer1234 But it's an SSD not an HDD like with most computers these days

Comment: @gogoud Even when I copy from partition to partition, I still get the same result, a steady 100MB/s when copying one large file, but slows to 800kb/s when copying 1000000 small 1kb files

Comment: I feel sure that copying inside an SSD should be much faster than this. Maybe some antivirus thing going on?

Comment: @gogoud No, its completely clean. Also at the beginning of the transfer it sais "Discovered 4,503,424 items" for like 60 seconds as seen in this picture: http://imgur.com/OpaBcai which I doubt is normal behavior.

Comment: @gogoud This is the same with my roommates PC, a single 8GB file his computer would copy in 7 seconds, however, a folder with thousands of files worth 5gb takes 50 seconds

Comment: For people to do more than guess, you will need to provide more information.  The make/model of the SSD, how it is connected, its age, the results of any tests you've run on its condition, background programs like virus checkers that could be affecting the time, etc.  Even without a moving head, there is still substantial overhead for small files.  You need to rule out things like the interface, a failing drive that is doing a lot of remapping, etc.  As @gogoud suggested, an active virus checker that is scanning each copied file would add massive overhead.

Comment: My SSD is a Samsung 850 EVO 512gb, and its age is about 4 months. No antivirus on my second partition (Windows installed on there too), but it is still slow. Curios, how much do you get when copying 40,000 1kb files?

Comment: When you copy to usb drives, make sure in the drive's properties, policies tab, it's set to optimize for speed (that enables write caching). But, don't ever remove the drive without telling windows first. PS: you'll never copy small files as fast as large files. It's like moving 100 matches one by one or all at once, which is faster?

Answer (score 1):

Because transferring even 1 byte file involves reading and writing of several kilobytes of data. The smaller file - the bigger overhead.

Comment: I do not understand your answer, what determines this speed, is it the proccessor speed, because even on my roomates PC (with a 700MBPS SDD copies small files at 15kb/s)?

Comment: The speed is roughly described by ratio (file_size / overhead_size) * throughput. What exactly determines speed is dependent on particular setup. Also, larger cache can be useful. In any case, it won't be very fast.

Comment: And what type of particular setup would make it faster (The processor speed, the RAM, or the video card, etc)... You still didn't explain the answer

Comment: I explained it perfectly: nothing will make it much faster and it is unclear what will make it a little faster. Small file transfers will be slow and it cannot be fixed.

Comment: My Azure hosted Windows Server copies lots of small files from one drive to another almost instantly, why is it fast on there then?

Comment: "lots" does not mean much. It has to be the same or a very similar number of small files in one directory. Big directory operations are very slow in NTFS.

Comment: It is the same folder that I copied from my regular PC to another partition, I uploaded the folder to Azure and moved it and it moved pretty much within 70 seconds (1GB folder with files 0.5-5kb in size)

Comment: Moving is always faster than copying; it does not involve any data transfer, unless across partitions.

Comment: @ikhd Moving is instant on both PC's (less then a second). It is the copying that takes time. When I said moving I meant from partition to partition.

Comment: not sure what fs is being used on your Azure system, but if it is like btrfs (for Linux) then copying a file within a partition does not involve making a new physical copy but just a new pointer to the existing file, this could be one reason why it is very fast.

Comment: @kirill2485  On your local machine, do you have File Explorer windows open while the copy is in progress displaying either the source or destination folders? These windows might be continually refreshing and slowing down the copy...

Comment: @gogoud No, still slow. I got a pretty good example: http://1drv.ms/1As9SkA

Download all the files, unzip them, and then permanently delete them, and you will see a screen that looks like this: http://imgur.com/WhsPWly

When it should take like 1 second it takes 45 seconds

Notice how it sais "Items/s" when you delete them.